# When try to call /shutdown on springboot, requeries authorization header instead just correct shutdown application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have app on spring-boot
added

```
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true 
endpoints.shutdown.sensitive=false
```

to application.properties

and try to call:

```
 curl -i -X POST devapp583.netcracker.com:26810/shutdown
```

But requres Auth header instead just shutting down:

```
{"errorCode":403,"userMessage":"No 'Authorization' header","stacktrace":null,"remoteMessage":null}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug, take a look [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5072). (If you use `@EnableResourceServer`)

> According to the docs for 1.3 for health access restrictions, a
>   non-sensitive health endpoint should allow anonymous access. However,
>   this stops working if the @EnableResourceServer annotation is found.
>   When the OAuth2 resource server is enabled, even non-sensitive
>   endpoints require full authentication.

Also there you can find a workaround:

> I did manage to work around the problem for the health endpoint by
>   adding the following bean definition.
>
> ```
> @Bean
> ResourceServerConfigurer resourceServerConfigurer() {
>     new ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {
>         @Override
>         void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)
>                 throws Exception {
>             resources.resourceId('blah')
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>             http.authorizeRequests()
>             // allow anonymous access to health check endpoint
>                     .antMatchers("/manage/health").permitAll()
>             // everything else requires authentication
>                     .anyRequest().authenticated()
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

However I have not tried it myself